# Куда двигаться web

Tags: веб-программирование

Всем добрый день, уважаемые web-разработчики
Кто в теме пожалуйста посоветуйте что изучать, какие языки и направления сейчас используются, что надо знать для того чтобы заниматься этим, может книги какие нибудь, или может где хорошо учат этому?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт,
ваш вопрос не по теме сайта => почитайте какие тут вопросы задают https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ------ а вот тут может что найдете для себя в виде ответа
https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5

Comment: вот еще ссылка https://liquidhub.ru/blogs/blog/s-chego-nachat-veb-razrabotchiku

Comment: Если популярное смотреть, то фронт vue3 + vite, reactjs. Бэк python + django, php, ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

для начала надо определиться для чего? если для себя - то надо и фонт и бэк знать. если просто сайтики - это одно, если что-то серьёзное - это другое. но как минимум - javascript, css3, html5. https://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Я хочу работать в этой сфере, прошел курсы Яндекса на фронтенда пытался даже брать какие нибудь заказы на кворке но чувствую что этого маловато, а там столько всего и вот ищю совета)

Comment: надо взять выбрать любой заказ и попробовать его реализовать, чисто для себя, и тогда будет видно , что необходимо